# removing certain words and combining tables

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to combine 2 large data frames adding a new column containing the source table names, below is a sample:

```
data1 = [['tom', 10, 'Unknown'], ['nick', '', 85], ['juli', 14]] 
Class1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['Name', 'Age', 'Scores']) 

data2 = [['Chris', 9, '98'], ['Abbey', '', 90], ['Alex', 10, ]] 
Class2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['Name', 'Age', 'Scores'])
```

I've tried several techniques like the below but none has worked:

`Class = pd.concat([Class1, Class2])`

`Class = pd.concat([Class1, Class2], join='outer')`

`Class = (pd.merge(Class1,Class2, how='outer')) [![enter image description here][1]][1]`

The expected result should look like this
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for add new columns before [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
Class = pd.concat([Class1.assign(Class='Class1'), 
                   Class2.assign(Class='Class2')], ignore_index=True)
print (Class)
    Name Age   Scores   Class
0    tom  10  Unknown  Class1
1   nick           85  Class1
2   juli  14     None  Class1
3  Chris   9       98  Class2
4  Abbey           90  Class2
5   Alex  10     None  Class2
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `pd.concat` with `keys` parameter:

```
pd.concat([Class1, Class2], keys=['Class1','Class2']).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  level_0  level_1   Name Age   Scores
0  Class1        0    tom  10  Unknown
1  Class1        1   nick           85
2  Class1        2   juli  14     None
3  Class2        0  Chris   9       98
4  Class2        1  Abbey           90
5  Class2        2   Alex  10     None
```